# android email with image in body from storage

Tags: android, email, html-email, email-attachments

i have an app in that i need to send email with text and img in body.... the img is comming from sd card like this

[image]
i've done this...

```
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
          emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
          emailIntent.setType("application/image");

          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");
          Spanned spanned_str_Caution = Html.fromHtml(str_Caution);
          String text=tv_viewinfo.getText()+""+spanned_str_Caution;
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);




            //  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/saved_images/test.PNG"));
            //  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/saved_images/test.PNG"));
             // root
              //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/saved_images/test.PNG"));
            //  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/saved_images/test.PNG"));
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
             finish();
             Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
```

but this not working for me and app crashes..

Comment: whats the error in logcat. post it

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        // intent.setType("text/plain");

        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        // intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Img Send");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        for (int k = 0; k < fmsgList.size(); k++) {
            File fileIn = new File(fmsgList.get(k));
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File file1 = new File(root, "/File.txt");
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(file1);
        uris.add(u);

        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        // startActivity(intent);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send E-mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

send path like this

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/saved_images/test.PNG"
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file_path);
```